# Some elementary decay estimates of solutions to the heat equation

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

**Preliminaries:** Let $u$ be the solution of the Cauchy problem for the heat equation with initial datum $u_0 \in L^1 \cap L^p$. Then I know that the following estimates hold: 
$$\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^p} \le Ct^{-\frac{N}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)}\Vert u_0\Vert_{L^1}$$
and $$\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^p} \le \Vert u_0 \Vert_{L^p}$$
where $N$ is the space dimension, $p \in [0,\infty]$ and $C$ a constant.

---

**Question 1:** Now let $q \in [1,2]$. and $u_0 \in L^q$
I'm not able to prove the following estimate  (which should be classical)
$$\Vert \partial^k_t D^\alpha u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^p} \le Ct^{-\frac{N}{2}\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}\right)-\frac{|\alpha|}{2} - k}\Vert u_0\Vert_{L^q},$$
where $p \in [q,\infty]$, $C$ is a constant, and $|\alpha|$ is the lenght of the multi-index $\alpha$.
How does one do it?

I've tried to compute
$$\partial_{x_k} K(t,x) = \frac{-x_k}{t}K(t,x)$$
$$\partial_{x_kx_k} K(t,x) = \left(\frac{x^2_k}{t^2}- \frac{1}{t}\right)K(t,x)$$
$$\partial_{t} K(t,x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{|x|^2}{t^2}- \frac{N}{t}\right)K(t,x)$$

(where $K$ is the heat kernel), but I don't see where this leads.

---

**Question 2:** To obtain the first estimates that I stated, I used the explicit form of the heat kernel. I guess one should use it to derive the last one too. Can we also obtain these estimates without making use of the form of the [heat kernel K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel)? That is, can we also obtain these estimates using the fact that for the heat kernel we have $$\mathcal{F} K_t(\xi) = (\pi/t)^{\frac{N}{2}}K_{(4t)^{-1}}(\xi),$$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform.

Comment: @WillieWong How does Q1 follow from interpolation? I've problems with the actual computation and estimates of the derivatives (I've added some computations to the question, but I don't know how iterating them leads to the desired estimate) and also with the more theoretical considerations of Q2

Comment: that's what I was not clear about: I was not sure whether your problem was going between $L^p$ spaces or that you just don't have the higher derivative estimates to start with.

Comment: @WillieWong The problem is mainly the derivatives' estimates.